# Redirection of python script output to file not working

Tags: python, linux

I have a simple python file on a Linux VM

```
import time
while True:
    print("test")
    time.sleep(10)
```

which I start with

```
python test.py  > test.log
```

but even after a longer time that file is empty

```
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf      0 Sep 29 07:57 test.log
```

Is the output cached or something? How can I make the output to go into the file right away?

I am pretty sure I forgot something very easy...

Comment: This is a LInux thing.  When stdout is redirected to a file, by default it is buffered.  There are several ways around it.  You can add `flush=True` to the `print` call, or you can disable buffering on `sys.stdout` by using the `-u` flag when you run Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change print like below

```
print("test", flush=True)
```